# What does this "forget" mean and how to use it?

Tags: grammar

How do you use this "forget"?

Forget that he is just a boy who has no experience!

Comment: If you read the sentence from a book, then it should be an imperative (implying *you* as the subject). However, if you found such a sentence in a chat room, it might be as well possible to imply either *let's* (still an imperative), or *I* (a declarative), depending on the context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Grammatically, "forget" here is a verb whose subject is "you". Its meaning  is not so clear because of its context. But we can say that "forget "means:

1. stop thinking or worrying about someone/something.
2. not caring about someone/something anymore.

Comment: You might note that this is an *imperative*, a command.